# About the second-order linear ODEs with polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that for $p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0$ :

When $p(x)$ is an incomplete-square quadratic polynomial, $q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, $r(x)$ is a linear polynomial, then the ODE relates to [Heun's Confluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E1).

When $p(x)$ is a complete-square quadratic polynomial, $q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, $r(x)$ is a linear polynomial, then the ODE relates to [Heun's Doubly-Confluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E2).

When $p(x)$ is a linear polynomial, $q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, $r(x)$ is a linear polynomial, then the ODE relates to [Heun's Biconfluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E3).

When $p(x)$ is a constant, $q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial, $r(x)$ is a linear polynomial, then the ODE relates to [Heun's Triconfluent Equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12#E4).

How about the types of the ODEs belonging when $p(x)$ is either an incomplete-square quadratic polynomial or a complete-square quadratic polynomial, $q(x)$ is a linear polynomial, or a constant, or even the $y'$ term vanishes instead?