# Algorithm for solving a large class of linear 2nd order ODEs with polynomial coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Let $\left\{ {\mathfrak P}_j \right\}_{j=0}^4$ be integers each of which is different from zero. Likewise let $p_1$,$p_2$,$q_1$ and $q_2$ be other integers that too are all different from zero.

From my answer to [Looking for closed form solutions to linear ordinary differential equations with time dependent coefficients.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899727/looking-for-closed-form-solutions-to-linear-ordinary-differential-equations-with) we know that every linear ODE of the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
v^{''}(x) + \frac{{\mathfrak P}_0+{\mathfrak P}_1 x + {\mathfrak P_2} x^2}{(p_1 x+q_1)^2 (p_2 x+q_2)^2} \cdot v(x)=0 \quad (I)
\end{eqnarray}
is always solved in terms of properly rescaled hypergeometric function .

In here I am going to present an algorithm that solves a more general ODE:
\begin{eqnarray}
v^{''}(x) + \frac{{\mathfrak P}_0+{\mathfrak P}_1 x + {\mathfrak P_2} x^2 + {\mathfrak P_3} x^3 + {\mathfrak P_4} x^4}{(p_1 x+q_1)^4 (p_2 x+q_2)^4} \cdot v(x)=0 \quad (II)
\end{eqnarray}
in terms of the doubly-confluent Heun function https://dlmf.nist.gov/31.12 .

The algorithm is as follows.

1. Consider a properly rescaled doubly-confluent Heun operator:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   {\mathfrak L}^{(a,q)}_{\delta,\gamma,e}(x):=\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \left( \frac{\delta}{x^2} + \frac{\gamma}{x} + e\right) \frac{d}{d x} + \frac{a x-q}{x^2} 
   \end{eqnarray}
   Note that every doubly confluent Heun operator can be brought into this form by rescaling the independent variable appropriately. Indeed changing $x \rightarrow e \cdot x$ results in ${\mathfrak L}^{(a,q)}_{\delta,\gamma,1}(x) \rightarrow {\mathfrak L}^{(a \cdot e,q)}_{\delta/e,\gamma,e}(x)$.
2. Generate some random $\left\{ {\mathfrak P}_j \right\}_{j=0}^4 \in {\mathbb N}_+^4$ and another random $(p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2) \in  {\mathbb N}_+^4$ and define $(A,B,C,D):=(p_1,q_1,p_2,q_2)$ .
3. Define five quantities $\left({\mathfrak A}_j\right)_{j=0}^4$ which are quadratic polynomials in the parameters $(\delta,\gamma,e,a,q)$ of the Heun operator . We have:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak A}_0&:=&-4 a B^3 D+B^4 e^2+g \left(2 B d D^3-2 B^2 D^2\right)+B^2 D^2 g^2+4 B^2 D^2 q+e \left(2 B^3 D g+2 B^2 d D^2\right)-4 B d D^3+d^2 D^4\\
{\mathfrak A}_1&:=&-4 a B^2 (3 A D+B C)+4 A B^3 e^2+e \left(2 B^2 g (3 A D+B C)+4 B d D (A D+B C)\right)+g \left(2 d D^2 (A D+3 B C)-4 B D (A D+B
   C)\right)-4 d D^2 (A D+3 B C)+2 B D g^2 (A D+B C)+8 B D q (A D+B C)+4 C d^2 D^3\\
{\mathfrak A}_2&:=&-12 a A B (A D+B C)+e \left(2 d \left(A^2 D^2+4 A B C D+B^2 C^2\right)+6 A B g (A D+B C)\right)+g \left(6 C d D (A D+B C)-2
   \left(A^2 D^2+4 A B C D+B^2 C^2\right)\right)+g^2 \left(A^2 D^2+4 A B C D+B^2 C^2\right)+4 q \left(A^2 D^2+4 A B C D+B^2
   C^2\right)+6 A^2 B^2 e^2-12 C d D (A D+B C)+6 C^2 d^2 D^2\\
{\mathfrak A}_3&:=&-4 a A^2 (A D+3 B C)+4 A^3 B e^2+e \left(2 A^2 g (A D+3 B C)+4 A C d (A D+B C)\right)+g \left(2 C^2 d (3 A D+B C)-4 A C (A D+B
   C)\right)-4 C^2 d (3 A D+B C)+2 A C g^2 (A D+B C)+8 A C q (A D+B C)+4 C^3 d^2 D\\
{\mathfrak A}_4&:=&-4 a A^3 C+A^4 e^2+A^2 C^2 g^2+4 A^2 C^2 q+g \left(2 A C^3 d-2 A^2 C^2\right)+e \left(2 A^3 C g+2 A^2 C^2 d\right)-4 A C^3 d+C^4 d^2
\end{eqnarray}
and solve a system of five coupled quadratic equations $\left({\mathfrak A}_j\right)_{j=0}^4=\left(4{\mathfrak P}_j\right)_{j=0}^4$ for the five parameters of the Heun operator.

4. Define the following functions:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   f(x)&:=& \frac{A x + B}{C x+D}\\
   m(x)&:=& f(x)^{-g/2} \sqrt{f'(x)} e^{\frac{d}{2 f(x)}-\frac{1}{2} e f(x)}
   \end{eqnarray}

Then the function:
\begin{equation}
v(x):= \frac{y(f(x))}{m(x)}
\end{equation} 
satisfies the ODE $(II)$ subject to $y$ being a solution to 
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak L}^{(a,q)}_{\delta,\gamma,e}(x)\left[ y(x) \right]= 0
\end{equation}

Below I enclose the implementation of this algorithm in Mathematica:

```
e =.; g =.; d =.; a =.; q =.; A =.; B =.; CC =.; DD =.; x =.;
{P0, P1, P2, P3, P4} = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 5];
{p1, p2, q1, q2} = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 4];

myinput = (P0 + P1 x + P2 x^2 + P3 x^3 + 
    P4 x^4)/((p1 x + q1)^4 (p2 x + q2)^4)

{A, B, CC, DD} = {p1, q1, p2, q2};
num = -(B CC - A DD)^2 {-4 a B^3 DD - 4 B d DD^3 + d^2 DD^4 + 
     B^4 e^2 + (-2 B^2 DD^2 + 2 B d DD^3) g + B^2 DD^2 g^2 + 
     e (2 B^2 d DD^2 + 2 B^3 DD g) + 4 B^2 DD^2 q, 
    4 CC d^2 DD^3 - 4 d DD^2 (3 B CC + A DD) - 
     4 a B^2 (B CC + 3 A DD) + 
     4 A B^3 e^2 + (-4 B DD (B CC + A DD) + 
        2 d DD^2 (3 B CC + A DD)) g + 2 B DD (B CC + A DD) g^2 + 
     e (4 B d DD (B CC + A DD) + 2 B^2 (B CC + 3 A DD) g) + 
     8 B DD (B CC + A DD) q, 
    6 CC^2 d^2 DD^2 - 12 a A B (B CC + A DD) - 
     12 CC d DD (B CC + A DD) + 
     6 A^2 B^2 e^2 + (6 CC d DD (B CC + A DD) - 
        2 (B^2 CC^2 + 4 A B CC DD + A^2 DD^2)) g + (B^2 CC^2 + 
        4 A B CC DD + A^2 DD^2) g^2 + 
     e (2 d (B^2 CC^2 + 4 A B CC DD + A^2 DD^2) + 
        6 A B (B CC + A DD) g) + 
     4 (B^2 CC^2 + 4 A B CC DD + A^2 DD^2) q, 
    4 CC^3 d^2 DD - 4 a A^2 (3 B CC + A DD) - 
     4 CC^2 d (B CC + 3 A DD) + 
     4 A^3 B e^2 + (-4 A CC (B CC + A DD) + 
        2 CC^2 d (B CC + 3 A DD)) g + 2 A CC (B CC + A DD) g^2 + 
     e (4 A CC d (B CC + A DD) + 2 A^2 (3 B CC + A DD) g) + 
     8 A CC (B CC + A DD) q, -4 a A^3 CC - 4 A CC^3 d + CC^4 d^2 + 
     A^4 e^2 + (-2 A^2 CC^2 + 2 A CC^3 d) g + A^2 CC^2 g^2 + 
     e (2 A^2 CC^2 d + 2 A^3 CC g) + 4 A^2 CC^2 q};
eX = Sum[num[[i + 1]] x^i, {i, 0, 4}]/(4 (B + A x)^4 (DD + CC x)^4) ;


subst = Simplify[
   Solve[num == {4 P0, 4 P1, 4 P2, 4 P3, 4 P4}, {e, g, d, a, q}]];
MatrixForm[subst]
Simplify[(eX /. subst) - myinput]

Clear[f]; Clear[m]; Clear[y];
f[x_] = (A x + B)/(CC x + DD);
m[x_] = E^(d/(2 f[x]) - 1/2 e f[x]) f[x]^(-g/2) Sqrt[
   Derivative[1][f][x]];
Clear[y];
v[x_] = y[f[x]]/m[x];

{e, g, d, a, q} = {e, g, d, a, q} /. subst[[1]];
FullSimplify[(v''[x] + myinput v[x]) /. 
  Derivative[2][y][
    x_] :> -(d/x^2 + g/(x) + e) y'[x] - (a x - q)/(x^2) y[x]]
```

[image]

Having said all this my question would be the following. Consider now a general linear 2nd order ODE with polynomial coefficients. What constraints should we impose on the coefficients so that the ODE in question can be mapped onto the ODE $(II)$ and therefore solved in terms of the doubly-confluent Heun functions as outlined in this post?

Comment: Can the above analysis convertible to the degenerate version so that to solve the linear ODE of the forms e.q. $(p_1x+p_2)^8y''(x)+(q_4x^4+q_3x^3+q_2x^2+q_1x+q_0)y(x)=0$ ?

Comment: @ doraemonpaul As far as I remember this case maps onto the tri-confluent Heun equation.